# Is it possible to send variables from HTML (index.html) to Reactjs?

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm new with html-react-node process. I want to know if it is possible to send a variable from html to React, and if so, how?

I've tried using `window.postMessage` but it seems to conflict with some parts of my code.

I am using Bootstrap, Tailwind, jQuery and w3school as plugin.

**HTML**

```
<script>
  function sendVariableToReact()
  {
     stringCut = $("#main").html();
     window.postMessage(stringCut, *);
  }
</script>
```

**REACT**

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener("message", console.log());
}
```

Comment: Hello Bor, welcome to stack overflow. When it comes to react you never write traditional HTML instead everything is in JSX. Please go through JSX and learn

Comment: If you wanna study react, easiest way to jumpstart is to watch or read tutorials about `create-react-app` . And also, just like what @PrajvalM said, you don't use tradtional HTML in react. Everything is in JSX.

Comment: Oh, I see. so i should place my code directly to react? I am still checking and learning some tutorials regarding this type of development :)